# How do I transfer gold between factions?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've got a character on Horde and now a brand new one on Alliance (same realm).  Problem is that the Alliance-side economy doesn't seem to be as lucrative at lower levels as its Horde-side equivalents.

Now that Blizzard has apparently cut off bidding on your own items from the same account, is there any way that I can transfer gold between the two characters without using two different accounts or someone else as an intermediary?

Comment: Paid Faction swap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this without an intermediary is to make use of the Paid Faction Transfer option.

Answer (score 3):

The Dungeon Finder reward [Satchel of Exotic Mysteries](http://www.wowhead.com/item=69903) that usually contains some gold(if not always cant remember) and can be send between factions. I used this to get a horde character started on a server I played alliance on. It is not much gold but it should be enough to get you started if you can run Dungeon Finder a couple of times a week as one of the needed classes.

Also you might get lucky and get a rare item that can be sold or a pet that is only sold on the opposite fraction than you need the gold. That should give you a couple of hundred gold to get started depending on rarity and number of cross fraction traders on server. Just remember to turn autoloot off before opening the satchel to look what was in it.

Other than that the only way as LessPop_MoreFizz said is Paid Fraction Transfer or finding someone on either side to help you with the transfer.

Comment: Never considered the satchel option before. Usually just got them and opened them right up. That's... incredibly helpful, thank you. And even if there were no rare items inside, the flasks are nothing to shake a stick at. At least Horde-side on my realm, anyway.